# interface function getting rvalue pointers to initialize shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I have a class exposing through it's interface add function:

```
void AddObject(Object *o);
```

Inside the class I maintain the objects in `set<shared_ptr<Object>>`.
Since I will create `shared_ptr` from the received pointer I thought to limit the function argument to only rvalue pointers so to make sure that the user will not delete the pointer I use. And so I'll change the function declaration to:

```
void AddObject(Object* &&o);
```

so a typical use will be:

```
AddObject(new Object())
```

preventing the user to accidentally delete pointer I hold.
I don't want to to use `shared_ptr` in the interface because the user is not familiar with `shared_ptr`.
Do you think my suggestion is a good idea?

Comment: What is wrong with a `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Well the same question applies if I used unique_ptr instead

Comment: I think `unique_ptr` makes it a little more obvious in the interface what you expect. Additionally, `move` semantics go hand-in-hand already with passing them around, so it's natural to `std::move` a `unique_ptr`, but really weird to `std::move` a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad idea. I'm sure there is a reason why `shared_ptr` c-tor that gets a raw pointer is marked explicit instead of using r-value. In my eyes, It's better to teach the users once about smart pointers or at least teach them about using `make_shared`/`make_unique` (which are safer and, in the case of `make_shared`, more efficient, BTW).

BTW, why `shared_ptr` and not `unique_ptr`?

Also, why `set`? Even if you want to make sure you hold each pointer only once and searching a `vector` each time doesn't look natural enough in your code, I don't see a reason to hold the pointers sorted instead of using `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this approach will not prevent the user from deleting the pointer. Consider this example

```
  auto obj = new Object();
  AddObject(std::move(obj));
  delete obj;
```

Secondly, the amount of steps between calling `new` and the creation of `shared_ptr` should be as few as possible. If anything happens inside `AddObject` before it can create a `shared_ptr`, the object will never get deleted.

The same applies if there are more arguments to `AddObject()`. If constructing those fails, you will leak memory.

```
  void AddObject(Object* &&o, SomeOtherObject* x);

  AddObject(new Object(), xx()); // if xx() throws, memory leak will occur
```

Ideally you would "wrap" object creating into `shared_ptr` construction:

```
  void AddObject(std::shared_ptr<Object> o);

  AddObject(std::make_shared<Object>());
```

Comment: you first example indeed show how user can delete provided pointer, but it's so explicit that only evil user will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following methods may solve your problem.

1. You may append more comments for `AddObject` to tell users that delete the pointer they added is not allowed. This is almost enough.
2. Or, you could also make `Object` inherits from a base class which has a **private** destructor and a method named `destroyByOwner`.